# Linq query problem (too many ado.net request)

Tags: c#, linq

I have trouble in my linq application.

I have **Orders**, **OrderChangeLog** and **OrderItems** tables. In 1 query i want to load orders and dependent tables. I use Linq.

```
 return from p in _db.dbOrders
 select new Order
 {
 ID = p.ID, 
 OrderStatusChangelog = new List<OrderStatusChangelog>( GetOrderStatusChangelog().Where(x => x.OrderID == p.ID)),
 Items = new List<OrderItem>(GetOrderItems(p.ID)), };
```

In this variant it takes too many ADO.NET requests (see image1)
[image1 full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLUzf.jpg)
[image: image1]

But. If i comment

```
Items = new List<OrderItem>(GetOrderItems(p.ID))
```

Perfect result ([image2 full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnZBo.jpg))
[image: image2]

Why one join work so?

P.S. My T-SQL (generated by LINQ):

```
{SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[UserID], [t0].[DateOrder] AS [DateCreated], [t0].[ControlGUID] AS [Guid], [t0].[StatusID], [t1].[ID] AS [ID2], [t1].[OrderID], [t1].[StatusID] AS [OrderStatusID], [t1].[Comment] AS [StatusMessage], [t1].[UserID] AS [UserID2], [t1].[Date], [t2].[FullName] AS [UserName], (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[dbOrderStatusChangelog] AS [t3]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[dbUsers] AS [t4] ON [t4].[ID] = [t3].[UserID]
WHERE [t3].[OrderID] = [t0].[ID]
) AS [value], [t0].[ShippingFLP], [t0].[ShippingAddress] AS [ShippingAddressContent], [t0].[ShippingRegionID], [t0].[ShippingCity], [t0].[ShippingZIPCode], [t0].[ShippingPhone], [t0].[ShippingMetroID], [t0].[PaymentFLP], [t0].[PaymentAddress] AS [PaymentAddressContent], [t0].[PaymentRegionID], [t0].[PaymentCity], [t0].[PaymentZIPCode], [t0].[PaymentPhone], [t0].[TrackingNumber], [t0].[DateShipped], [t0].[ShippingCost] AS [Rate], [t0].[ShippingName] AS [Name], [t0].[ShippingTypeID], [t0].[PaymentName] AS [Name2], [t0].[PaymentTypeID], [t0].[SourceID], [t0].[CustomerComment], [t0].[CustomerEmail], [t0].[CustomerFLP], [t0].[DiscountAmount] AS [discountAmount], [t0].[DiscountReason] AS [discountReason], [t0].[Amount]
FROM [dbo].[dbOrders] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([dbo].[dbOrderStatusChangelog] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[dbUsers] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t1].[UserID]) ON [t1].[OrderID] = [t0].[ID]
WHERE (CONVERT(Int,[t0].[StatusID])) IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)
ORDER BY [t0].[ID] DESC, [t1].[ID], [t2].[ID]}
```

Table diagram
[image: tables]

**UPD1**

```
 private IQueryable<OrderItem> GetOrderItems(int orderID)
    {
        return from p in _db.dbOrderItems
               where p.OrderID == orderID
               select new OrderItem
                          {
                              ID = p.ID,
                              ItemPrice = p.Price,
                              OrderID = p.OrderID,
                              Quantity = p.Quantity,
                              Product = new Product
                                            {
                                                ID = p.ProductID,
                                                Name = p.ProductName,
                                                Brand = new Brand { Name = p.dbProduct.dbBrand.Name }
                                            }
                          };
    }


    private IQueryable<OrderStatusChangelog> GetOrderStatusChangelog()
    {
        return from p in _db.dbOrderStatusChangelogs
               select new OrderStatusChangelog
                          {
                              Date = p.Date,
                              ID = p.ID,
                              OrderID = p.OrderID,
                              OrderStatusID = p.StatusID,
                              StatusMessage = p.Comment,
                              UserID = p.UserID,
                              UserName = p.dbUser.FullName
                          };
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why SO images are not clickable... you need to drag them to the address bar for god sake... :D

Comment: What is the code for `GetOrderItems` and `GetOrderStatusChangelog`?.. Lists force enumeration, you can leverage `IQueryable` to offset the load to be on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Items = new List...
```

This will cause an enumeration of the items you are querying, forcing the call to the database for each list that is created (and elements copied).

You can defer enumeration and the call to the consumer and have them convert the items to a list, or you can create a method that will create a list for them on demand or change the way they will interact by making your definition an `IEnumerable` and just returning the `IQueryable`.

The real question is, is it required for each item to be a list and to be fully populated on the main query or can you delay execution until the data is actioned upon?

Comment: A List _IS_ IEnumerable - I think you meant IQueryable?

Comment: Yes, I can you delay execution until the data is actioned. But GetOrderItems and GetOrderStatusChangelog similarity. And work bad only GetOrderItems(); GetOrderStatusChangelog  - work good

Comment: @Basiclife No, I didn't, `IQueryable` is `IEnumerable` too, but if the signature of `Items` was changed from `List` to `IEnumerable` he could get rid of the calls to the list constructor and simply return `GetOrderItems` etc. which would defer loading to the actual enumeration of the set.

Comment: @Quintin - Understood. I hadn't realised it was the List constructor that caused the enumeration.

Comment: unfortunately I do not fully understand. You can set an example code?

Comment: @Dmitriy Yes, change the `Items` property definition on the `Order` object from `List<OrderItem>` to `IEnumerable<OrderItem>` (if it already is `IEnumerable<OrderItem>` that is okay) then change the population statement from `Items = new List<OrderItem>(GetOrderItems(p.ID))` to `Items = GetOrderItems(p.ID)`.

Comment: unfortunately there are too many code use IList. But i change it to **LazyList** (which was previously) and it works! I don't know What happed) it's fun. Thanks